# Exclude certain parts of typescript file from transpilation?

Tags: typescript, parcel

Is it possible to compile most of a typescript file - except for 2 or 3 lines - which you don't want to be touched?

Comment: The question is why you would want to exclude part of a file from transpilation? You'd be completely cutting off the ability for that page (or application) to be viewed in Internet Explorer.

Comment: it's a very odd scenario - in essence I have a code editor which I want to put code samples into for the user to view. Rather than converting the code sample into a string by using some online encoder, I would like to just directly write out the function and use the `.toString()` method. However, if I do so, the comments inside the function will get stripped out due to transpilation. While I could just keep the comments in the source code - I would rather just not have comments for those particular lines.

Comment: Is a template literal (a multiline string literal delimited by backquotes) good enough for embedding your samples without requiring too much quoting?